# Abrir y cerrar 2 ventanas modal en xcode (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

agradezco al grupo de personas profesionales en el campo para la siguiente cuestión.

al presiona un boton se abre un modal, sin embargo, el modal debe disponer de un boton para cerrarse asi mismo y abrir un nuevo modal.

Dicho de otra manera les comparto a continuación el objetivo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo que tengo es el siguiente

```
let popup : SignUpViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignUpViewController") as!
        SignUpViewController
    
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: popup)
    
    navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
    self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            
    
    let walkhidden : WalkthroughViewController =
        self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WalkthroughViewController") as!
        WalkthroughViewController
    
    walkhidden.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Gracias muchachos por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tu segundo modal siempre se abrirá cuando se cierra el `WalkthroughViewController` puedes mandar a llamarlo desde el completion del dismiss

```
walkhidden.dismiss(animated: true) {
    openSignUp()
}

func openSignUp(){
   //TODO: Código para mostrar la pantalla Sign Up
}
```

Comment: Gracias amiga, voy a indicar tu respuesta como la mejor para proximas personas que podrian tener el mismo problema y tu solución los puede apoyar, sin embargo en mi caso he hecho unos ajustes pero casi con el mismo problema en el siguiente enlace, si me puedes ayudar porfavor.  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/494925/cambiar-de-view-controller-en-un-modal